# is it possible to add background image to jdesktop pane

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create virtual desktop. I complete successfully.But i am not able to set background image for jdesktoppane. I want to set background image and After adding image also the desktop pane  work normally.Is anyone know means just tell me
                                              Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this thread at coderanch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/342361/Swing-AWT-SWT-JFace/java/Adding-background-image-JDesktopPane), a possible solution is to paint in the paintComponent method of your subclass of the JDesktopPane (or in your renderer for this class, which could be better).

Comment: Thank you so much .The example in this link works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

You can extend JDeskTopPane class with another member as image and then in constructor set the background to that image.

```
    public ExtendedJDesktopPane(Image image) {
         super();
         this.image = image;
    }

  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
     g.drawImage(scaledImage, 0, 0, this);
  }
```

EDIT:
This is similar to the link provided below by Riduidel.. i just got late writing it.